# Cant connect php application to AWS rds instance

Tags: php, database, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect my PHP application to AWS rds. I have done all the steps and finally  when i write the connection like this:

```PHP
$link = mysqli_connect($_SERVER['amazon-endpoint'], $_SERVER['myMasterUserName'], $_SERVER['myMasterUserPassword'], $_SERVER['ebdb'], $_SERVER['3306']);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
die("database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" .
mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
}
```

I get this error:
database connection failed: No such file or directory (2002)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create a security group which allows your public ip to RDS instance.
The check you could connect to RDS Db using mysql command line
Then

```
$con = mysqli_connect("yourAmazonEndPoint","UserName","Password","your_db");
```

[check this for security groups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vE2E7cYJ0IQ)

from console :

```
mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p
```

or

```
mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=rds-ca-2015-root.pem
```

Comment: is there anyway to test your instance.
like to see what`s the exact error when you are trying to connect through mysql console (guess port is right?). Have you tried like this from your console after allowing your IP . mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p or    if you use a pem - mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=rds-ca-2015-root.pem